# Angular JS - Issue accessing ui-router $stateParams in a ng-repeat filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having an interesting problem accessing a ui-router $stateparameter on a partial after being sent from a parent page.

The code on the partial is (the parameter passed is 'uid'):

```
Part A: {{uid}}
Part B: <div ng-repeat="x in contacts | filter:{id:uid}: true">{{x.name}}</div>
```

Interesting, the parameter {{uid}} is displaying correctly in Part A. But it does not work correctly when used in the filter component of Part B. It seems to be an issue with passing the $stateParameter to the filter.

However, if I set the variable as a constant in my $stateProvider it works (but of course, not what I want it for):

```
.state('admin-panel.default.pascon-persons.detail', {
    url: "/:userid",
        templateUrl: 'app/pascon-book/pascon-persons.persons.tmpl.html',
        controller: function($scope,$stateParams) {
            $scope.uid = 7; //set as a constant instead of $stateParams.userid 
        }
})
```

Alternatively, if I set the filter to a constant it also works (also not what I want).

The variable is being passed like so:

```
<md-grid-tile  ui-sref=".detail({ userid: x.id })"...
```

Is there another way that $stateParameters are to be used in filters? Or am I just doing something silly :{

Thanks for any input.

Nige

Comment: I have found that removing the ': true' condition on the filter enables the $stateParams variable to be accessed properly. However, I need this condition to provide an exact match of the id (as opposed to an id that contains the id value).

I will now look into why the ':true' condition is breaking the code in this case.

Comment: This works:

    '<div ng-repeat="x in contacts | filter:{id:uid}">{{x.name}}</div>'

... but does not give exact match, but this breaks the code:

<div ng-repeat="x in contacts | filter:{id:uid}: true">{{x.name}}</div>

Any ideas why? Is it something to do the ng-repeat making several instances of the state?

Comment: You have a space after `:` and before `true`. Is that it?

Comment: (Friendly fyi - check out [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting))

Comment: Thanks. the space did not affect it. However, I did manage to fix the issue by changing the parameter to 'user_id' instead of 'id' in all cases. 'id' must have been conflicting somewhere in my, although I can not see where.

Thanks @AdamZerner for the heads up on formatting ;P